# Angularjs custom directives over regular html

Tags: angularjs

Can someone explain to a learner What are the benefits of using custom directives in anjular over normal html elements, can someone give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal html directive and custom directives are like `Inbuilt functions` and `user defined` functions.

Custom directive is a powerful feature of AngularJS.

You can create user defined tags which act like normal tags. So if you are creating a custom tag (directive), you are contributing a new tag to html (Note: custom directives can only be used by angular pages.).

**Advantages**

All advantages of user defined functions can be listed here.

**Example**

Consider a scenario, you want to display address of your company in your html more than one,

normal html would look like,

```
<div>
    <p> Tuition Wiki </p>
    <p> Connecting Tuition Teacher and Students </p>
    <p> www.tuitionwiki.com <p>
    <p> info@tuitionwiki.com </p> 
<div>
```

You need to rewrite this set of html codes where ever you want to display company details.

You can wrap this set of codes into a custom directive and you can use your custom directives to replace this set of code.

```
<company-address> </company-address>
```

This will be the code to display your company address.

```
myApp.directive( function(){
    return {
       template : '<p> Tuition Wiki </p> ....' // here you can write your html
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You separate their logic from the rest of application, code can be easily reusable.
2. You give "normal" html a meaning, which helps you a lot to understand what does the element do when you see it in a source code.

For example:

```
<dropdown>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</dropdown>
```

vs

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Of course, you can argue with that saying "but I can achieve the same result using meaningful css classes", but what if that classes are assigned with some css rules (from external css you cannot change for example)? Using directives gives you more flexibility here.